# Why `QComboBoxListView` documentation is not available at qt.io

Tags: qt, qwidget

I'm trying to get information about `QComboBoxListView` to understand that *"How `QComboBox` and `QComboBoxListView` are related?"*.

I understand that, on GUI level, when we click on `QComboBox` then `QComboBoxListView` is shown as a drop-down. But *"How `QComboBoxListView` is related to `QComboBox` and is shown when `QComboBox` is clicked?"*.

I suspect that, Qt creates `QComboBoxListView` and populate it with items of `QComboBox`. But not sure.

I'm not able to find information about it on *Qt*s official documentation website [doc.qt.io](https://doc.qt.io/).

Moreover, in Google search also, I'm not able to find information about it, except the following link and I'm not sure about authenticity of presented information:
https://cep.xray.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.8.6-browser/df/d2d/class_q_combo_box_list_view.html

I'm interested in following information there:

- Link for information about `QComboBoxListView`
- How `QComboBox` and `QComboBoxListView` are related? Relationship diagram will be very helpful

I'm using Qt version 5.12.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as far as you are using Qt 5.x `QComboBoxListView` should not be available for direct usage (AFAIK it existed all by itself in Qt 4.8).

If you check the Qt's code base, the mentioned class can be found in [qcombobox_p.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox_p.h.html) which means it is a part of the `QComboBox`'s implementation details. This header is commonly used for PIMPL of the widget and for some support/helper classes like in this case.

It also means that there is no guarantee that in future versions of Qt that class would not change or perish. Why using it at all?

---

There was also a question about relationship. Well, if there *is* some need to know that, sources show something like the following:

1. `QComboBox`'s private implementation (PIMPL) *contains* `QComboBoxPrivateContainer` (derived from QFrame)
2. `QComboBoxPrivateContainer` *contains* some view, `QComboBoxListView` by default, it can be changed via the well-documented `QComboBox::setView`
3. `QComboBoxListView` is an *ancestor* of `QListView` with some view options customized

Comment: Thanks for your answer :). Regarding _Why using it at all?_, I'm working with Qt source code and need to change some functionality as per my need. Off-course, I can dig into the code to get my all answer, but it will be much time consuming and may be I'll not be able to see the **complete picture**. That's why I'm looking for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`QComboBoxListView` is a private "helper" class used within `QComboBox`. There is no documentation because it is not part of the official (public) API/library. You can/should peruse [the code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox_p.h#n84) of the class for more information (I find [this cross-linked version](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox_p.h.html#QComboBoxListView) to be easiest to follow w/out downloading the code locally).

Comment: @maxim-paperon Thanks for your answer :)